# Создать изображение контрола

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Мне нужно создать изображение контрола. Делаю таким образом

```
public static BitmapFrame CreateControlFrame(FrameworkElement control)
{
    var width = control.ActualWidth == 0 ? control.Width : control.ActualWidth;
    var height = control.ActualHeight == 0 ? control.Height : control.ActualHeight;
    var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Math.Ceiling(width), (int)Math.Ceiling(height), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bmp.Render(control);
    return BitmapFrame.Create(bmp);
}
```

но это работает только если у меня контрол находится на форме и он видимый. А мне надо создать изображение контрола, которого нет на форме или он скрыт (`Visibility = Hidden/Collapsed`)

В идеале вот так

```
var btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "qwe";
btn.Width = 100;
btn.Height = 30;
WpfControlRenderer.CreateControlScreenshot(btn, "ss.png");
```

Может кто знает как?

Comment: если он невидимый, то значит он и неотрендереный? Как тогда с него получить изображение? :-/

Comment: @Sublihim, а что тогда делает класс с таким громким названием как `RenderTargetBitmap`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266116/how-to-get-a-screen-capture-of-a-net-winforms-control-programmatically

Comment: @user2455111, это для WinForms

Comment: Как вариант для отрисовки можно не сворачивать контрол, а прятать его за другими, тогда он будет нормально рендериться в изображение.

Comment: @iRumba, логично было бы где-то нарисовать этот контрол, а потом рендерить в битмапу :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868631/render-a-not-visible-wpf-controls-to-an-bitmap-image

Comment: @Shakra, не очень хороший вариант, учитывая, что элемент может выйти за видимую область. в этом случае он обрезается

Comment: @iRumba хм, я думал что при импользовании актуальных размеров элемента, он отрендериться в картинку целиком.

Comment: @Sublihim, работает. Если оформите, тыкну галочку. Ну, с переводом там и все такое и ссылкой на источник. И желательно еще иметь способ определить, является ли элемент отрисованным, чтобы вызвать отрисовку по надобности а не вызывать ее каждый раз. Там по ссылке много кода. он не нужен. Достаточны вызовы `Measure()` и `Arrange()` для контрола

Comment: @Shakra, возможно так и будет, но я для быстроты проверки просто выставил минусовые маргины. В любом случае выставлять маргины на время в 0 для скриншота это фэйл, потому что мне придется делать ооочень много скриншотов на автомате + контролы будут плодиться с потоками вместе, а выполнение я от потока UI отделить уже не смогу и это все будет вызывать бешенство формы wpf

Comment: @iRumba, как достоверно определить был ли контрол размещен в лайоутере или нет - вот это вопрос. Просто как минимум 2 признака: Если вы сами только что его создали и не засунули в визуальное дерево, то понятно, что он не отрендерен, если он скрыт - значит лайоутер его исключил из рендеринга. Сам рендеринг и лайоутинг - асинхронные операции. Так что по большей части, кажется, что проще ориентироваться на косвенные признаки.

Comment: @Sublihim, если я передаю в функцию, которая делает картинку из контрола, этот самый контрол, то как функция поймет, что он только что создан и не отрисован?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На этот вопрос уже был дан ответ на англоязычном *stackoverflow*: [Render a “not visible” WPF controls to an bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868631/render-a-not-visible-wpf-controls-to-an-bitmap-image)

Для контрола необходимо вызывать методы `Measure` и `Arrange`, для их лайоутинга, и только потом - рендерить:

```
var btn = new Button();
btn.Content = "qwe";
btn.Width = 100;
btn.Height = 30;

var size = new Size(250,250);
btn.Measure(size);
btn.Arrange(new Rect(size));

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(250, 100, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

bmp.Render(btn);

PngBitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

using(var s = File.OpenWrite("image.png"))
    enc.Save(s);
```

Comment: Если есть возможность, подскажите как определить, отрисован ли элемент (то есть чтобы не вызывать `Measure` и `Arrange`

Comment: @iRumba можно, наверно проверить свойство `IsLoaded` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.isloaded(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: А что мешает перед рендером создать контрол и выделить ему место и расчитать его размеры (Measure и Arrange). Далее можно проверять что контрол создан, значит больше не нужно менять размеры, но это будет работать при условии что контрол имеет фиксированный размер, не изменяемый между отрисовками в изображение.

Comment: @Shakra, ресайз формы или наличие сплитеров могут поломать эту концепцию, наверно

Comment: @Sublihim так зачем добавлять контрол на форму?

Comment: @iRumba Я-то откуда знаю :) Подробности, надо у топикстартера спрашивать )