# Сделать скриншот сайта без видимости браузера

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Вот тут 
[Создать изображение контрола](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613653/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0)
спрашивал про скриншот контрола, вопрос решен, но с браузером (`WebBrowser`) это не катит. Браузер фотать нужно чуть иначе, но проблема не в этом. Когда я создаю браузер в коде, он не переходит на страницы.

```
LoadCompletedEventHandler h = null;
h = (o, e) =>
{
    WpfControlRenderer.CreateControlScreenshot((FrameworkElement)o, destFileName);
    _wb.LoadCompleted -= h;
};
_wb.LoadCompleted += h;
var size = new Size(_wb.Width, _wb.Height);
_wb.Measure(size);
_wb.Arrange(new Rect(size));
_wb.Navigate(url);
```

В функцию `h` даже не заходит. При этом браузер, добавленный на форму отлично все открывает и фоткается. Ему чего то не хватает, но я не знаю чего.

**UPD:**

События `WebBrowser.Navigating` и `WebBrowser.Navigated` срабатывают. Но `WebBrowser.LoadCompleted` почему то не происходит

Comment: А скажите вам вообще нужен контрол `WebBrowser`? Или просто скриншот определённого сайта?

Comment: ну, контент в WebBrowser - это вам не контрол :) LoadCompleted не срабатывает, потому что WPF - не идиот, чтобы загружать контент и давать лишнюю нагрузку на рендер.

Comment: @Sublihim, спасибо, вы очень помогли мне сейчас )))

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov скриншот нужен. Желательно при минимальной нагрузке, потому что скриншотов потребуется несколько тысяч.

Comment: @iRumba Смотрите я вам могу предложить такое решение: Чистая консоль без визуализации контрола-браузера и скриншоты. Просто вводите URL — получаете скриншот. Можете также предварительно выполнить любой JavaScript (что-то модифицировать на странице), если надо. Вам такое подойдёт?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю поможет ли, но есть ответ на *stackoverflow* ["Converting WebBrowser.Document To A Bitmap?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006825/converting-webbrowser-document-to-a-bitmap).
Правильный ответ на вопрос дан пользователем *webspy*.

Вот пример его кода:

```
class NativeMethods
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("0000010D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IViewObject
    {
        void Draw([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwAspect, int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, [In] IntPtr ptd, IntPtr hdcTargetDev, IntPtr hdcDraw, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref RECT lprcBounds, [In] IntPtr lprcWBounds, IntPtr pfnContinue, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwContinue);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    public static void GetImage(object obj, Image destination, Color backgroundColor)
    {
        using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destination))
        {
            IntPtr deviceContextHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            RECT rectangle = new RECT();

            rectangle.Right = destination.Width;
            rectangle.Bottom = destination.Height;

            graphics.Clear(backgroundColor);

            try
            {
                deviceContextHandle = graphics.GetHdc();

                IViewObject viewObject = obj as IViewObject;
                viewObject.Draw(1, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, deviceContextHandle, ref rectangle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            }
            finally
            {
                if(deviceContextHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    graphics.ReleaseHdc(deviceContextHandle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
NativeMethods.GetImage(webBrowser.ActiveXInstance, screenshot, Color.White);
```

Единственное **"но"**, этот пример использует браузер из *WinForms*. Но вам никто не запрещает создать экземпляр этого класса в памяти и получить скриншот.

Comment: Неплохо. Если вы сами разобрались в том что тут написано, может подскажете еще способ узнать высоту загруженной страницы, чтобы сделать скриншот во всю высоту?

Comment: @iRumba. Скорее всего, надо запросить размер загруженного контента у самого браузера `webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height`, соответственно его видимо и надо выставить как высоту битмапы

Comment: @iRumba, если это не подойдет, то есть более грандиозный способ вычислить высоту и ширину контента. Могу добавить в ответ, если надо. Правда, там один момент меня смущает, как отреагирует невидимый браузер на изменение его высоты и ширины.